# ReactNative error: Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:checkDebugManifest'

Tags: android, react-native

I started to work on a react native project. But I have a problem now. I built a simple project and execute `react-native run-android`. But error occurred.

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 954 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 6 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
40 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 28 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests'.
> Failed to create directory 'E:\web_project\fcManager\app\svn_prj\02_source\fcmanager\android\app\build\intermediates\compatible_screen_manifest\debug\createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests\out'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run 
CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests'.
> Failed to create directory 'E:\web_project\fcManager\app\svn_prj\02_source\fcmanager\android\app\build\intermediates\compatible_screen_manifest\debug\createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests\out'      

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

And then I cleared the cache by `yarn start --reset-cache`, and execute again `react-native run-android`. Error again. But the latter errors are different from the former errors.
What could be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. I solve the problem.

```
>cd android
android>./gradlew clean
```

And then apk is successfully installed on the emulator.